# MoviePlayer local File

Tags: ios, video, swift, xcode6

So I have been trying to find the answer to this problem for about 16 hours now.  It seems like it should be such a simple thing but apple's documentation on this is pretty bad and I don't understand objective C very well.

So I have a SKSpriteNode which I would like to use as a button.  When that button is clicked I would like to play a mp4 video in full screen.  Sounds pretty simple right?

Also I am writing this in the Game template because I learned the little swift I know with that, and I only work in GameScene.swift.

I have already gone in to my Build Phase and added the video to "Copy Bundle Resources".

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var infoButton:SKSpriteNode!
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!
    var url: NSURL!



    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // Button
        let infoButtonTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "btn_vid")
        infoButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: infoButtonTexture)
        infoButton.position = CGPointMake(backgroundSprite.size.width * 0.393, backgroundSprite.size.height * 0.2437)
        infoButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        infoButton.name = "infoButton"
        self.addChild(infoButton)

        // Video
        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hue", ofType: "mp4")
        let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle()!.URLForResource("hue", withExtension: "txt")
        url = NSURL(string: "hue.mp4")

        moviePlayer.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
        moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
        moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            println("Something has Been Touched")
            var location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var node:SKNode!
            node = self.nodeAtPoint(CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y))

            if node.name {
                if node.name == infoButton.name {
                    moviePlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to remove non relevant code.

As you notice in the video section, I have three different methods for getting the file path.  I have run println on all of them and they print out as follows:

filePath prints as: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/954CB013-FB55-4846-A8E0-A2773A3563FF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/35DB47D4-FB78-4FBE-898B-A5B3435A0F6C/Kiosk-Wine.app/hue.mp4

bundleURL prints as:file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/954CB013-FB55-4846-A8E0-A2773A3563FF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/35DB47D4-FB78-4FBE-898B-A5B3435A0F6C/Kiosk-Wine.app/hue.mp4

url prints as: hue.mp4  (you probably could have figured that out)

I have used moviePlayer.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(x) on each of them where x is filePath, bundleURL, or url and the errors are as follow:

filePath: Thread:1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
In the Output window it shows:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

bundleURL: This one fails to Build : Missing Argument for parameter isDirectory in call

url: This one fails to build: Missing Argument for parameter isDirectory in call

I hope that I have given enough information for you to get a good idea of the problem, if not please let me know and I will post it.

Thanks!

Bonus Question:  If anyone knows the code to recognize a "click down" and a "release" for a sprite node in touch so that I can change the texture  image of the sprite node when someone is touching it that would be amazing :)  Or even know where I can read about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("hue", withExtension: "mp4")

moviePlayer.contentURL = url
moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

I don't have a lot of experience with files but this is what a fellow stackoverflow user suggested in some post when I was looking for a way to play a video in my app.

Comment: This worked when I changed the whole program over to UIKit rather than based on SpriteKit